# PHP merge arrays by value, put into table - best structure?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array of results:

```
 Array
  (
      // 1st big array of results
      [0] => Array
          (
              [0] => Array
                  (
                      [customer] => John
                      [shop_name] => shop1
                      [shop_address] => address1
                  )

              [1] => Array
                  (
                      [customer] => John
                      [shop_name] => shop2
                      [shop_address] => address2
                  )

              [2] => Array
                  (
                      [customer] => Mark
                      [shop_name] => shop1
                      [shop_address] => address1
                  )

          )

      // 2nd big array of results
      [1] => Array
          (
              [0] => Array
                  (
                      [customer] => Cathy
                      [shop_name] => shop3
                      [shop_address] => address3
                  )

              [1] => Array
                  (
                      [customer] => Cathy
                      [shop_name] => shop4
                      [shop_address] => address4
                  )

              [2] => Array
                  (
                      [customer] => Maria
                      [shop_name] => shop3
                      [shop_address] => address3
                  )

          )

  )
```

There are **unique pairs** of `shop_name` and `shop_address` for each customer in each big array of results.

**What I'd like to do**

I'd like to put each `customer` of *1st big array* in one `<th></th>` but its `shop_name` and `shop_address` in individual `<td></td>` like this:

[What I'd like to do - Table IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64xGV.png)

And of course repeat that process for *2nd big array*.

**Do I have the best structure of array to do this?**

Or maybe I should put each `customer` in its own array:

```
// Give each 'customer' its own array

foreach ($array[0] as $result) {
   $array_by_customer[$result['customer']][] = $result;
}
```

But as you can see I can do that only for `array[0]` - *1st big array of results*.

[Array by customer - PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bdhi-703z)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were on the good way : make an array per customer.

I suggest you do this for all results in array, and that's it !

```
foreach ($array as $big_array_key => $results) {
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $arrays_by_customer[$big_array_key][$result['customer']][] = $result;
    }
}
```

Then your $arrays_by_customer will contain two big arrays : one for each for your initial big arrays.

Comment: My answer was a little bit short... I think you were on the good way : make an array per customer. This way you may fill in one $array_by_customer per initial big array if you want to format separate tables.

Comment: But how do I put each `$array_by_customer` in their initial big array?

Comment: Just keep your initial array as this, if you need it. Use the intermediate array only for presentation purpose.

Comment: Maybe I'm trying to make it more complex than it actually is in my head but I don't understand. I need `John` and `Mark` to put into one separate table and `Cathy` and `Maria` into another table.